# Heavy DOM manipulation performance

Tags: javascript, dom, web

I'm doing heavy DOM manipulation in JS.
What I do today is creating element (not linking it to document) - perform all heavy stuff on that element, when all completed, linking it to document.

I assume this should be fine - as element is not linked to document during manipulations.

However I reviewed several topics on that, and people were talking there about using:

- documentFragment
- display = none

Is that anything I should consider, or it's equivalent to what I already do.
Is there any advantage of creating documentFragment over creating regular element as I do?

Any good articles you can propose on that topic?

Thanks!

Comment: `documentFragment` is useful if you are manipulating whole structures of elements and want to insert them in the DOM all at once.